# av_free crashes application randomly - FFMPEG C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav

I am trying to create a simple media-player for an introduction to the world of ffmpeg, the problem is that every time that I call `av_freep(void*ptr)` the application crashes.

If I don't call `av_freep` I get a memory leak and the memory used by the program increases up to 1000MB (Already measured), here is the code:

```
int16_t* audioBuffer=(int16_t*)av_malloc(AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE+FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);

if(!audioBuffer){
    MessageBox(0,"Error allocating in audioBuffer","Error: Mem",MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK);
    return -1;
}

int sz = MEDIA->DecodeAudioFrame((void*)audioBuffer,0);

Pa_WriteStream(MEDIA->output_stream,(int16_t*)audioBuffer,MEDIA->_audio_ccontext->frame_size);

av_freep(audioBuffer);
```

Here is my 'DecodeAudioFrame' function code:

```
int WbMedia::DecodeAudioFrame(void *audio_buf, int buf_size){
static AVFrame frame;
static AVPacket pkt;
static uint8_t *audio_pkt_data = NULL;
static int audio_pkt_size = 0;

int len1=0;

for(;;){
    bool do_rt = false;


    while(audio_pkt_size > 0){
        int obt_frame = 0;

        len1 = avcodec_decode_audio4(_audio_ccontext,&frame,&obt_frame,&pkt);
        if(len1 < 0){
            audio_pkt_size = 0;
            break;
        }

        audio_pkt_data+=len1;
        audio_pkt_size-=len1;

        if(obt_frame){
            data_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(frame.linesize,channel_count,sample_fr,_audio_ccontext->sample_fmt,1);
            memcpy(audio_buf,frame.data[0],data_size);
        }

        if(data_size < 0){
            continue;
        }

        if(pkt.data){
            av_free_packet(&pkt);
        }
        return data_size;

    }

    if(pkt.data){
        av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }

    if(do_rt){
        return data_size;
    }

    // Try to get a new packet
    if(!audio_packets.empty()){
        WaitForSingleObject(Queue_Audio_Mutex,INFINITE);
            pkt = audio_packets.front();
            audio_packets.pop();
        ReleaseMutex(Queue_Audio_Mutex);

        audio_pkt_size = pkt.size;
        audio_pkt_data = pkt.data;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I need help with this issue, I don't know if it is a bug or what I need to do. What's happening there? Why does it crashes on the `av_freep` call? How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Try `av_freep(&audioBuffer);` [Doc:](http://wiki.aasimon.org/doku.php?id=ffmpeg:av_freep) `NOTE: ptr should be declared as a void**`

Comment: Changed `av_freep` argument to `&audioBuffer`, now, it still crashing but this time the debugger points to the `memcpy` on the `DecodeAudioFrame`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`av_freep` takes a *pointer to the pointer* you want to free; it sets the freed pointer to `NULL` afterwards. Therefore, you need to use it as

```
av_freep(&audioBuffer);
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
av_free(audioBuffer);
audioBuffer = NULL;
```

which is equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the last error is fixed, but now I am getting a new error. The debugger is telling me that the problem comes in the `memcpy` of the function `DecodeAudioFrame`

Comment: That's clearly a different issue. Make sure you aren't passing something invalid as `data_size`, e.g. -1.

Comment: I'll check what's happening there. I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks anyways, I'll try to keep looking what's going on the memcpy

Answer (score 0):

```
int16_t* audioBuffer=(int16_t*)av_malloc(AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE+FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
```

This is wrong. `AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE` is deprecated (removed in new versions). With the new decoding API you can get larger decoded frames than this.

```
static AVFrame frame;
```

No. Do not allocate AVFrame on stack, it will break. Use `avcodec_alloc_frame()` (or `av_frame_alloc()` with new versions).

```
data_size = av_samples_get_buffer_size(frame.linesize,channel_count,sample_fr,_audio_ccontext->sample_fmt,1);
```

You realize you're oveerwriting the original frame linesize (AKA the plane size), right? I wonder if that is intended.

Also, what is `sample_fr`? Is that some constant from somewhere? Just use AVFrame.nb_samples.

Finally, your code apparrently assumes interleaved audio (i.e. the audio samples for all the channels interleaved in one buffer). Many decoders now output planar audio (i.e. the samples for each channel in a separate buffer). This might be the reason for the crash, since `av_samples_get_buffer_size` calculates the total size for all the samples in all channels, while `data[0]` will contain only the samples for the first channel.

If planar audio is indeed the reason, you should either modify your code to support it, or use [libavresample](http://libav.org/doxygen/master/group__lavr.html#_details) to convert planar to interleaved